# Redirecting to sender view URL displays an error

Tags: docusignapi

#### When I redirect to a generated "sender" URL, DocuSign displays a page that states

```
Login Unsuccessful
Sorry, an error occured. Please try again.
retry.
```

---

#### Details

Our code hasn't changed in months, and today is the first day I have become aware of this problem. Previously, the user would get logged in and would be allowed to modify the envelope before sending. Here are the details regarding the initial envelope being sent:

- Sent as API account (*ApiAccount*) on behalf of a user (*UserAccount*)

We are then creating a "sender" view for the *UserAccount*.

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restApi/v2/accounts/{ApiAccount}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"{ApiAccount}", "Password":"{ApiAccount_Password}", "SendOnBehalfOf": "{UserAccount}", "IntegratorKey":"{IntegratorKey}"}
Content-Type: application/json
```

---

#### Results

The DocuSign API returns the URL as expceted:

```
"url": "https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=2a289ba9-69ff-4986-946e-3b1c25b9db67&DocuEnvelope={envelopeId}&send=1"
```

When I navigate to the provided URL, I get the above error message displayed in the HTML. The URL that displays this error message is:

```
https://appdemo.docusign.com/authentication?back=/prepare/{envelopeId}/add-fields
```

---

#### Additional Details

I have done the following:

- Confirmed that the API and user account logins are both valid (passwords are correct).
- Ran DocuSign logging on the user account (that should be logged in). No logs were generated to indicate what the problem was.
- Our code that generates the redirection URL has not changed in months and worked correctly until today. **Also, doing a simple AJAX POST like above displays the error.**
- This is for the *demo* environment.

Comment: Is this still an issue? Apparently we had some hiccups in demo. I tried embedded sending in demo just now and it worked fine.

Comment: This now works as of this morning. Thanks for the update!